# JavaScript нужна небольшая помощь

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который берет элемент по `id` , пробовал и по классу, добавляет к нему класс при `mouseenter`. Код изменяет первый попавшийся ему элемент с таким `id`, или с class, хотя у меня их больше 5.

Как изменять **все** эти элементы?

```js
var one = document.querySelector('.img1');

    one.addEventListener('mouseenter',function add()
        {
            one.classList.add("changes");
        });
    one.addEventListener("mouseleave",function remove(){
        one.classList.remove("changes");
    });
```

```html
<div class="blockOne"><img class="img1" src="home/1.png"></div>

<div class="blockTwo"><img class="img1" src="home/2.png"></div>
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, document,getElementsByClassName('classname') - должен возвращаться массив с элементами, а дальше что хотите, то и делайте с ними. А что насчет id, то в принципе вы не можете создавать элементы с одинаковыми id. Если, конечно, мне не изменяет память.

Comment: jQuery или цикл, и не по id а по класу. Id должен быть уникален у каждого элемента.

Comment: Сообщение поправил, код прикрепил

ситуация та же, первый элемент с классом img1 изменяется, а следующий уже нет. Если первый вырезаю, изменяется второй, а нужно чтоб на какой элемент наводил, тот и изменялся

Comment: Не нужно копировать ответ в тело вопроса, нужно отмечать ответ принятым, нажав на галочку под ним.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.img1').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    this.classList.add("changes");
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    this.classList.remove("changes");
  });
});
```

```css
.changes {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockOne"><img class="img1" src="home/1.png" alt="1.png"></div>
<div class="blockOne"><img class="img1" src="home/2.png" alt="2.png"></div>
```

Comment: Можете разьяснить пожалуйста этот момент: forEach(item =>..

Comment: @Nikita В данном случае это то же самое, что `forEach(function(item) {`.